# how to store many date range with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a booking system for an hotel where `owners` can edit `Room` schedules.

For storing the dates when a `Room` is *not available*, my first intuition was a table `Occupancy`:

```
Occupancy.create from: "01-04-2022", to: "31-05-2022", room: @room
Occupancy.create from: "15-04-2022", to: "15-05-2022", room: @room
```

I will end up with overlapping `Occupancies`, but thats ok.

But now, I would like the `owner` to be able to **choose to make the `Room` vacant during the first weekend of April**.

And I don't see how to do that with this schema, unless creating another table, or adding a column to `Occupancy`.

So, I was thinking of storing an array of occupied dates in a column of the `Room` table, using maybe `json` format.

But I feel I might struggle when I will need to query the available rooms for a given period.

It doesn't sound the right tool for the job.

Comment: You can prevent overlapping ranges using an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on a booking system in the past that was modeled similarly to your current approach, and it worked fine. We had an equivalent to `Occupancies` called `Bookings` and had a second table of `InternalHolds` that were used for the usecase you're describing, as well as for other tasks like cleanings or maintenance.

This worked perfectly fine for a long time. Eventually, we ended up extracting out a denormalized table of bookable calendar days, but it was derived from the bookings and holds.

At larger scale and on a longer time horizon, you may end up with some dedicated search infrastructure outside of Postgres (think geographic search, amenity filtering, and full-text search), which will require this kind of denormalization anyway.

I would hesitate to jump straight to a JSON column approach, as the querying would just be more tricky. You'd either be stuck writing tricky non-portable SQL for a lot of queries; or loading every occupancy, for all rooms, for all time to be able to answer a query like "What rooms are available for a 3 night stay starting Tuesday".